# How to identify elements classname containing special characters using Selenium and VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, classname

I'm trying to learn more about how Selenium works with VBA and I'm trying to do somethings about the trendings behaviors of ecommerce nowadays.

In this case, I don't know how works the FindelementByclass when it has special characters like `_` or `-` inside, because it always gives me empty result and I need to identify it because I want to go through every class called as it.

```html
<span class="minificha__sku ng-binding">Cód TG: AS0-322</span>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To identify the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementByClassName* I:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByClassName("minificha__sku")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByClassName* II:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByClassName("ng-binding")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByCss("span.minificha__sku.ng-binding")
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//span[@class='minificha__sku ng-binding']")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

space in class means it has two classes,

class="minificha__sku ng-binding"

means it has "minificha__sku" and "ng-binding" , so use xpath or css instead of byclass or use either of the two class not two

**css:**

```
span[class="minificha__sku ng-binding"]
```

**xpath**

```
//span[@class="minificha__sku ng-binding"]
```

Comment: I understand, but it doesn't work for what I need to do, or I guess that's what's is causing issues in my script, can you give me an example using css?

Comment: Your css pattern is wrong as compound classes need to be joined by "." i.e. minificha__sku.ng-binding unless you intended to insert a descendant combinator in there and look for a child node?

Comment: I didn't understand